# Do we need to update Orbeon?

Tags: orbeon, xforms, exist-db

We are trying to use the **fr:error-summary** component inside a 4 year old orbeon project but we can't make it work. We get the following error message:

```
Error Message

Cannot load "/xbl/orbeon/error-summary/error-summary.xbl" with webapp loader

Exception Class org.orbeon.oxf.resources.ResourceNotFoundException
```

The project is now using orbeon v3.7.1 and exist v1.3. Is this error due to an out-of-date build of orbeon? If not, how can orbeon be configured in order to make these lines work?

```
<fr:error-summary observer="my-group">
    <fr:label>Your Form Contains the Following Errors</fr:label>
</fr:error-summary>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't use `fr:error-summary` in 3.7.1 because it was not available as an separate, reusable component in that release.

You can see how it's hooked up in Form Runner in 3.7.1 [here](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/tag-release-dev-3.7.1/src/resources/apps/fr/components/view.xsl#L414) and [here](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/tag-release-dev-3.7.1/src/resources/apps/fr/includes/error-summary-model.xml).

Comment: Thanks Erik, do you know if that version of `fr:error-summary` (v3.7.1) has this same bug? [link to bug explanation](http://orbeon-forms-ops-users.24843.n4.nabble.com/Bug-found-in-v3-7-1-td4655619.html)

Comment: I don't understand your question.